# Converter used on Binding with no path gives value as DataRow

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm auto-generating a grid from a DataTable, and some of the columns need to be converted to more complex layouts than just text. I've successfully applied DataTemplates dynamically where needed, however I cannot run a converter (IValueConverter) because the value it is being given is the DataRow, so I have no way to tell which piece of data I need from the array.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here is relevant code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DateColumn">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource DateConverter}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

---

```
public class DateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's because the DataContext at that point is the DataRow. You need to tell the Binding to pass a particular piece of it into the Converter. You mentioned in the title "with no path" - well, why aren't you giving it a path?

Comment: @Tim There is no path because it's binding from a dynamic DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by setting the converter in the code instead of trying to select the template in the xaml. Here is what it looks like now:

```
column.DataMemberBinding.Converter = new DateConverter();
```

Note that this is for a Telerik grid. I believe the syntax on a normal data grid is "`Binding.Converter`" instead of "`DataMemberBinding.Converter`".

Comment: This doesn't work, however, if you need to use a template that is set up in xaml, like if you need to convert the data to a specific image.